# Javascript output only showing once

Tags: javascript

How come I can only output a render from javascript once? I try to show it again and it doesn't work?

```
$(function() {
    $('#access').keyup(function () {
        var access = $('#access').val();
        var note = $('#note'),

        // Notice the *1000 at the end - time must be in milliseconds
        ts = (new Date(access * 1000)).getTime() + 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

        $('#countdown').countdown({
            timestamp: ts,
            callback: function(days, hours, minutes, seconds) {

                var message = "";

                message += days + "<small class='white'>D</small>, ";
                message += hours + "<small class='white'>H</small>, ";
                message += minutes + "<small class='white'>M</small>, ";
                message += seconds + "<small class='white'>S</small>";

                note.html(message);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Then I call the javascript here and it works fine.

```
    Pre-sale ends in <span id="note"></span>
```

But then further down the page I try to show it again with the same html code, but it's blank on the second one. Doesn't work!

Comment: can you show your issue in a fiddle?

Comment: Please, provide a jsfiddle.

Comment: do you have an element with an id of  `countdown` in your HTML? (sorry, needs to be asked as we cannot see your HTML) - better yet, can you add your HTML to the question?

Comment: I posted the HTML in my original question, not sure why you guys are saying I didn't.

Comment: Nope, not all of it... I can only see the HTML inside your JS but not the rest (i.e. what does `#countdown` look like, or `#access`) - could you add it again?

Comment: It's there, I'm looking right at it as I type this.

Comment: Miklós Tusz's answer worked perfectly actually. Thanks guys!

Comment: here: http://massblogprofits.com/img/html.png

Comment: Oh, I can see that!!! but you did not read my comment then.  Where is the HTML for #countdown? or #access? or, indeed, the rest of the HTML?

Comment: Not sure why you would need that, everything that has to do with this issue is above. Anyway it is resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using id's in the html, which can only be used once per page. Switch `#note` to `.note` and `#countdown` to `.countdown` in your javascript, and add the class to the two elements and it will show up.

Comment: since we have not seen the HTML, how can you be sure this answers the question?

Comment: I posted the HTML in my original question, not sure why you guys are saying I didn't.